# How to delete a item in model respect to the id using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my schema

```
var purchaseOrderModel = function () {
    var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        strBarCode: {type: String },
        strItemName: {type: String },
        strQuantity: {type: String }
    });

    var purchaseOrderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        strSupplierID: {type: String, required: true },
        strInvoiceNo: {type: String,required: true },       
        dteInvoiceDate: {type: Date, required: true },

        items: [itemSchema],

        created_by: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }
    });



    return mongoose.model('purchaseorder', purchaseOrderSchema);

};

PurchaseOrder.find({items._id:req.params.itemid}, function (err, items) {
    return items.remove(function (err) {
    });         

});
```

How to delete a items in purchaseOrderSchema respect to the id.
items are stored using itemSchema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)** update operator to remove the items from an array as follows:

```
PurchaseOrder.update(
    { "items._id": req.params.itemid },
    {
        "$pull": {
            "items": {"_id": req.params.itemid}
        }
    },
    function (err, doc) {
        if(err) { /* handle err */}
        console.log(doc);
    }
);
```